# C# Console Application WebBrowser

Tags: c#, console-application, webbrowser-control

I have a normal console app .net core project with some classes, but I can't use a web browser. I want to navigate to a specified URL but with the web browser like in windows forms application, not just to start a process of my chrome. Like `webbrowser.navigate` function but I can't use it I don't know why?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Console applications are strictly text-based. Text in, text out, cursor position and not much else.  They cannot have any UI controls or output.  As such UI components such a text boxes, dropboxes, WebBrowser, etc. won't work as you expect if they work at all.   While the console application may be hosted in a window (so you can see the output), your access is limited to what can be controlled via the Console class, which doesn't include any graphics or direct access to the window.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=net-5.0

Your only real options are to launch a browser (or other application), or convert your application to a non-console application capable of displaying graphical controls like WebBrowser.

It is technically possible to use WebBrowser in a console application (See https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/197007/How-Use-WebBrowser-without-winform), but be aware it won't actually display anything on screen, so it's use is limited.